# migrating from Delayed Jobs to Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am migrating from Delayed Jobs to Sidekiq. There are some spec that I already have and I also want to change them to become compatible with sidekiq.

```
it { expect(Delayed::Job.select{|job| job.handler.match(/MyJob/)}.size).to be 0 }
```

This basically checks that there are no MyJob DelayJobs scheduled. How can I test the same thing for the same job in sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `Delayed::Job`, but from your tests, seems like you're testing if the size of your queue is 0, right? If so, Sidekiq have a section that explains some tests that you can do [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing), and, with the instructions on that page, about your configuration for use Rspec, you can do something like

`it {expect(MyJob.jobs.size).to be_eql 0 }`

Also, if you like more tests options, take a look at [this gem](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq).

Answer (score 0):

With `Sidekiq` if you are using the basic usage where you set up your own worker for a specific job, i.e. `MyJobWorker`.  Then in the code you would use it like so:

```
MyJobWorker.perfom_async(id: 5)
```

Then in your spec it's as simple as asserting that the worker has that number of jobs:

```
it { expect(MyJobWorker.jobs.size).to be(0) }
```

`Sidekiq` has some pretty good [docs on testing](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-delay-and-delay_for-methods).

In order to give a more specific answer please include more of the code for how you are setting up your `Sidekiq` worker and how you are using the worker.